# nodejs express function not returning the variable from fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have the following function in my nodejs, using express.

```
function metaInfo (id){

    var dir = 'files/'+id;
    var count = 0

    fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + dir+'/myfile.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

        if (err) throw err;
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var myArr = obj.nodes;
        var count = Object.keys(myArr).length;
        console.log("counting :", count)
    });

    return count
};
```

when I call this function, the `count` is zero, however, it is the right value inside the `fs.readFile` . how can I return the updated value of `count`?

Comment: what does myArr return if you log it out?

Comment: You'll need to use a synchronous readFile function (google that), otherwise the code in that callback function happen separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fs.readFile is asynchronous, you'll need to use a callback or a Promise for example.

Callback :

```
function metaInfo (id, cb){

    var dir = 'files/'+id;
    var count = 0

    fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + dir+'/myfile.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) cb(err);
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var myArr = obj.nodes;
        var count = Object.keys(myArr).length;
        console.log("counting :", count)
        cb(null, count)
    });
};
```

And you use it like this :

```
metaInfo(1, function(err, result) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Count:', result);
});
```

With a Promise:

```
function metaInfo (id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var dir = 'files/'+id;
        var count = 0

        fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + dir+'/myfile.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            var myArr = obj.nodes;
            var count = Object.keys(myArr).length;
            console.log("counting :", count);
            resolve(count);
        });
    });
};
```

You'll use it like this :

```
metaInfo(1)
    .then(function(count) { console.log('Count:', count); 
    .catch(function(error) { throw error; };
```

(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

You could also use the readFileSync method of the fs module (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)

Or the async/await, but be careful of compatibility (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: thanks, how can i include two `fs.readFile` and pass count1 and count2 as the result of the function?

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readFile` is an asynchronous function, so when your function returns `count`, the file has not been open yet.

Here's what you can do :

```
function metaInfo (id, callback){

    var dir = 'files/'+id;
    var count = 0

    fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + dir+'/myfile.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

        if (err) throw err;
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var myArr = obj.nodes;
        count = Object.keys(myArr).length;
        callback(count);
    });
};

metaInfo("yourId", function(count) {
  // Here is your count
});
```

OR

use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)

[Here is a good example](http://www.daveeddy.com/2013/03/26/synchronous-file-io-in-nodejs/)

Hope it helps,

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

fs.readFile is an async call.

you can use a function as a callback and invoke it ad the end of your async call or you can wrap your call in a promise

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var MyReadFileAsync = function (filename) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, 
         data) {

        if (err) reject(err);
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var myArr = obj.nodes;
        resolve(Object.keys(myArr).length);
    });

    });
};

MyReadFileAsync(__dirname +'/' + dir+'/myfile.json').then(function(counter){
 var myCounterUpdated = counter;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an asynchrone problem with your code.

You sould use the "async" library for NodeJS. [Async documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/)

For exemple, you can wrap your :

```
fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + dir+'/myfile.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

    if (err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var myArr = obj.nodes;
    var count = Object.keys(myArr).length;
    console.log("counting :", count)
});
```

To :

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' + dir+'/myfile.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

            if (err) throw err;
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            var myArr = obj.nodes;
            var count = Object.keys(myArr).length;
            console.log("counting :", count);
            callback(null, count);
        });

    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals  = count
    return result;
});
```